# Dictionary of dictionaries in loop in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, nltk

I am trying to build dictionary, where each key has a value that is dictionary itself.
The problem with following code that it doesn't append new item to dictionary when new if is done

```
dict_features = {}
def regexp_features(fileids):
    for fileid in fileids:
        if re.search(r'мерзавец|подлец', agit_corpus.raw(fileid)):
            dict_features[fileid] = {'oskorblenie':'1'}
        else:
            dict_features[fileid] = {'oskorblenie':'0'}

        if re.search(r'честны*|труд*', agit_corpus.raw(fileid)):
            dict_features[fileid] = {'samoprezentacia':'1'}
        else:
            dict_features[fileid] = {'samoprezentacia':'0'}
    return dict_features
```

Result is dict

```
{'neagitacia/20124211.txt': {'samoprezentacia': '0'}, 'agitacia/discreditacia1.txt': {'samoprezentacia': '0'}
```

But I need

```
{'neagitacia/20124211.txt': {'oskorblenie':'1', 'samoprezentacia': '0'}, 'agitacia/discreditacia1.txt': {'oskorblenie':'0', 'samoprezentacia': '0'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rewriting the value for the same `fileid`.

In your code,

```
if re.search(r'мерзавец|подлец', agit_corpus.raw(fileid)):
    dict_features[fileid] = {'oskorblenie':'1'}
else:
    dict_features[fileid] = {'oskorblenie':'0'}

if re.search(r'честны*|труд*', agit_corpus.raw(fileid)):
    dict_features[fileid] = {'samoprezentacia':'1'}
else:
    dict_features[fileid] = {'samoprezentacia':'0'}
```

For one `fileid`, you create the first one and then replace it using the second `if-else` construct. (Both the `if-else` constructs put values since either the `if` or the `else` will always be executed)

What you may be looking for is a `defaultdict` with `dict` as the default value. Something along the lines of -

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> a = defaultdict(dict)
>>> a['abc']
{}
>>> a['abc']['def'] = 1
>>> a
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'abc': {'def': 1}})
>>> a['abc']['fgh'] = 2
>>> a
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'abc': {'fgh': 2, 'def': 1}})
```

So, your code may change to

```
dict_features = defaultdict(dict)
def regexp_features(fileids):
    for fileid in fileids:
        if re.search(r'мерзавец|подлец', agit_corpus.raw(fileid)):
            dict_features[fileid]['oskorblenie'] = '1'
        else:
            dict_features[fileid]['oskorblenie'] = '0'

        if re.search(r'честны*|труд*', agit_corpus.raw(fileid)):
            dict_features[fileid]['samoprezentacia'] = '1'
        else:
            dict_features[fileid]['samoprezentacia'] = '0'
    return dict_features
```

Comment: Thanks! I have tried dict_features[fileid]['oskorblenie'] = '1'  but without default dict it produced KeyError. Now it works.

Comment: @VicNicethemer : That's the way defaultdicts work, for non existent keys they give a default value to the key, using which you can assign stuff to it. Glad my answer was helpful. :)